# Can a grounded metal electrical box be mounted to a metal plate?

Tags: electrical

I only have space to mount a grounded metal box to a metal wall plate in my ceiling. Any issues with this?

[image]

Comment: No grounding issue, but it could be a structural one. It's not likely to be an issue though if it's just enough to hang a box..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pic didn't exactly show the metal plate.  If you are referring to a splicing or mending plate for the bottom cord of a truss, you are ok, as it is just metal on wood.

Your box must be accessible, regardless of what it is mounted to.

Comment: "Box must be accessible without having to disturb the building's finish" +1

Comment: Yeah that looks like it might be a strut for a can light (ordinarily in a ceiling), but insufficient context.  And that looks like ceiling plaster or drywall below the box...